# Print characters in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a loop

```
for (var i=0; i < x; i++){
  // ..
}
```

I want to wrap each 8 numbers between two characters. So my output would look something like this:

```
< 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 > < 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 > < 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 > < ...
```

My solution was

```
if(i == 0) console.info('<');
if(i == 7) console.info('>');
if(i == 8) console.info('<');
if(i == 15) ...
```

But this would be pretty verbose. Is it possible to make this task easier?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `i` falls between 7 and 8 using the `%` (mod) operator. `x % y` returns the remainder if dividing `x` by `y`. For example:

`0 % 4 == 0`

`1 % 4 == 1`

`2 % 4 == 2`

`3 % 4 == 3`

`4 % 4 == 0`

`5 % 4 == 1`

A solution using this method would look like:

```
var limit = 64;
console.info('< ');
for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
  if (i % 8 == 0 && i > 0) {
     console.info('> <');
  }
  console.info(i, ' ');
}
console.info('>');
```

Comment: You can try `console.log(i, ' ')` as well.

Comment: Although your `console.info()`s aren't in all the optimal places, this is the best answer here so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.info('<');
for (var i=0; i < x; i++){
    if ((i > 0) && (i %8) == 0) {
        console.info('><');
    }
}
console.info('>');
```

Basically, what we are doing here is saying, if i divided by 8 has a remainder of 0, then add the brackets.  Thus, every 8 numbers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
var iterations = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    console.log("<");
    for (var j = i * 8; j < ( i * 8 ) + 8; j++)
        console.log(j);
    console.log(">");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
(function() {
  var result = "";
  var x = 25;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (i % 8 == 0) {
      result += "> <"
    }
    result += " " + i + " ";
  }
  result += " >"
  console.log(result.substring(1));
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion,

```
var limit = x/8;
var chunk;
for (var i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    console.log('<');
    chunk = i*8;
    for (var j=chunk; j<chunk+8; j++)
        console.log(j);
    console.log('>');
}
```